# How to fix padding in ZStack

Tags: swiftui, padding, zstack

I have ZStack with two views one of which can be shown due to the condition:

```
ZStack{
            VStack{
                ...
            }.padding(.all,17)
            
            if handler.bottomVisible {
                BottomSheetView(handler: handler, player: true)
            }
        }
```

but when I uncomment these lines:

```
if handler.bottomVisible {
    BottomSheetView(handler: handler, player: true)
}
```

my `.padding(.all,17)` for VStack becomes damaged. Without this view, everything looks ok, but after adding the second child view for ZStack UI doesn't see paddings for VStack. Maybe I did smth wrong?

Example without bottom sheet:

[image]

and with the activated condition:

[image]

Comment: Needed minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Asperi, which details do you need? I thought that this info is enough :(

Comment: seems like your `BottomSheetView` which is on top, covers the padding area of your VStack. add a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: As a minimal reproducible example, in this case, you can provide different images of the layouts,  so that the differences can be seen visually.

Comment: @Yodagama I have added example

Comment: @Asperi, I have added example

Comment: @cedricbahirwe, thank you for your response, I couldn't understand what I needed to add :)

Comment: @Andrew what is the expected view?

Comment: @Yodagama, first one, I need to save paddings but also need to have bottom view too. Together I can't unite them

Comment: You should look into your `BottomSheetView` size (frame), It looks like It might have a bigger size than the parent's available space.

Comment: I have set frame size but it didn't fix the problem at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well hard to answer your question because there is not so much code but you can try...

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {

....
} .padding()
```

or you add the padding (.all, 17) information to all your textfields like

```
VStack{
    Text("Hello Stackoverflow")
    .padding(.all,17)
}
```